# Which is faster `Model.where(:attribute)` or `Model.find_by_attribute_id(id)`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called `Max`.

Which will be a faster way to find this record:

Assume that `user` is a local variable already set.

```
Max.where(:user_id => user.id)
```

or

```
Max.find_by_user_id(user.id)
```

Assume that this query will be run frequently, and there is an index for the `user_id` column on the `Maxes` table.

Is there any benefit to going one way or another? i.e. one produces less queries but runs slower or vice versa?

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Both work, but I am not sure how to measure the differences.

Comment: Read the log output with the timing info next to the SQL statement? Count the number of SQL statements produced (although I'm not sure what makes you think one would produce more statements)?

Comment: Have you tried comparing these methods with large data like `User.find(User.all.map(&:id))` and `User.where(id: User.all.map(&:id))` ?

Comment: I have not, but that is a good idea.

Comment: I actually just tried it, its exactly the same queries (and execution time of course).

Comment: For me...the `where` query took 0.1ms longer on a small dataset - i.e. less than 10 records. So not sure if that is a good example. Btw, you are right...the queries are identical.

Comment: I tried with 52 User objects in my DB, same execution time (in average). I tried again with more than 600 records, had the same execution time (in average).

Comment: Don't 'waste' your time on comparing them. Dynamic finders (`find_by_xxx_and_yyy`) are *mildly* deprecated now. They are cumbersome, hard-to-read, error-prone. It's even hard to guess the result of calling them: will it be an error if nothing is found, will it be an array or a single (first?) value. You have to stick to the `where(args)` version for the future. I hope they will be removed soon at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principal advantage with the `.where` method is that is **returns an ActiveRecord::Relation** (acts like an array, **can be empty** if no record match the conditions given). The other big advantage of `.where` is that you can **chain** them, very usefull for scopes!

With the `.find`, it **returns the Object or raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound** error.

---

So imagine you have no user matching the id you're passing:

```
Max.find(-1) # => Raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Project with ID=-1

Max.where(id: -1) # => Returns an empty ActiveRecord::Relation, doesn't raise an error
```

### Update

I tried and compared the 2 following in my IRB console (~620 records in the DB)

```
User.find(User.all.map(&:id))
User.where(id: User.all.map(&:id))
```

It **produces the same query**, and **takes the same execution time**.

Comment: This is strange: `find_by_xxxx` don't have to rise an error. The `find_by_xxx!` should (with `!` at the end).

Comment: However, depending on how it's viewed, it's appropriate to return 1 or 0 records (or raise an exception). In C#/LINQ I use `Single[OrDefault]` (returns single record) instead of `Where` (returns sequence) .. so I would not say it is a "principle advantage"; it has different semantics for different tasks.

Comment: @jdoe you are right, I never knew that an has been estonished of this behavior! Thanks for the comment, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the miniscule bit of ruby code that needs to run, they are identical.

Check your development log.  They generate the *same SQL*.

I prefer the new AREL form -- it's much more general, only executes when needed, and chainable.